# LaTeX/knitr/sweave table with references to R objects

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, sweave

I'm using knitr/R-sweave to produce a pdf-document wit LaTeX-code. I want to make a table with some numbers produced by some R calculations in the R-code-chuck above this table. When I usually want to refer to an R object in the LaTeX/knitr-outout I use `\Sexpr{}`, but it doesn't seem to work within tables.

Here's what I got:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<Chunk1>>=
a= "1%"
b= "2%"
c= "3%"
d= "4%"
e= 1
f= 2
g= 3
h= 4
@

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Simple stratified data splits}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\textbf{Dataset} & \textbf{Observations}     & \textbf{Event rate}\\ \hline
Full data        & \Sexpr{e}                & \Sexpr{a}         \\
Training set     & \Sexpr{f}                & \Sexpr{b}         \\
Test set         & \Sexpr{g}                & \Sexpr{c}         \\
Evaluation set   & \Sexpr{h}                & \Sexpr{d}        
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This gives "Running pdflatex.exe on test.tex...failed"

I get the following from the log

> LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.
>                  Default added (so using `tbp') on input line 71.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size (Font)
>
>   <7> on input line 75. LaTeX Font Info:    External font`cmex10'
>   loaded for size (Font)              <5> on input line 75.
>   [1{C:/Users/Frederik
>   Hermann/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
>
> ] (test.aux) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  1244
>   strings out of 493634  16308 string characters out of 3143709  72572
>   words of memory out of 3000000  4665 multiletter control sequences out
>   of 15000+200000  4116 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000
>   for 9000  1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 
>   27i,8n,19p,284b,237s stack positions out of
>   5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s  Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 39879 bytes). PDF statistics:  18 PDF objects out of
>   1000 (max. 8388607)  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)  1
>   words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

I'm quite the rookie. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like this question is primarily about LaTeX, in which case you may have more success on [tex.se]. But make sure you read their help center first, and don't cross-post.

Comment: When I have this issue, I go through the painful row by row process. Start with the simplest table, add a row, ...

Comment: Cross-posted here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/308573/36408 ...

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting things like "1%" or "2%" into the table.  The percent symbol is a comment marker in LaTeX, so the rest of the line will be dropped.

You can fix this by using "1\%", "2\%", etc. (so that the percents are escaped).  You need the double backslash in R code so that a single backslash makes it through to LaTeX.